# How to get Netradio working in Firefox

Tags: firefox

I listen to a Danish Stateowned Netradio, but I cannot get it working. I have installed the Adobe Flashplayer, but apparently there are some problems with the plugin, so when I push the playbutton nothing at all happens, and none of the other browsers work either.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean dr.dk. I experimented and got the radio working, but then it froze up and nothing happened, and then I noticed the pop-up blocking symbol in `firefox`. You need to allow pop-ups for the site and save it to the `firefox` preferences by going to edit > preferences > and clicking on 'exceptions' next to block pop up windows and add dr.dk in there. Then you need to reload dr.dk/radio in a new tab (or restart firefox but make sure you don't clear the settings on exit) and then click on one of the radio stations and a pop up player will appear. It was fine after that for me- see the second screenshot.

[image]
[image]